# Have vs Have been

Tags: verbs, conditionals, passive-voice

1. If Jim had taken Sandra to a romantic film, she wouldn't **have been**
   so frightened.
2. If I hadn't missed the train, I wouldn't **have been** late.
3. If she had known the address, she would **have been** able to help them.
4. If I had told Sarah the truth, I would **have** felt much better.

All of them are in 3rd conditional and I'd like to know why some of them uses 'have been' (1st, 2nd and 3rd) but 4th one is with just 'have'?

Usually 'have been' appears in passive voice (as in I've been told) or present perfect continuous (as in I've been waiting here..) right?

But they are not in passive voice and we can't have the same with 'intransitive verbs' as it doesn't make sense, also this is not present perfect continuous as well. Then what rules are these belongs to?

Comment: I'd like to advise you to visit our sister site [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), but please make sure you take the [tour](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit their [Help Center](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help) before posting any question.

Comment: Past participle forms should follow "have". The past participle form of to "be" is "been" and to "feel" is "felt".